# How Native Libraries are part of the APK file

Tags: java, android, native, libraries

The APK file consists of the Dalvik executable, Resources and Native Libraries.How does Dalvik machine code contain abstraction code such as these native libraries? It would only make since if they are libraries in machine code like DLL or LIB's.

Answer (score 1):

The native libraries are delivered as .so files (specifically, ELF dynamic libraries as it typical on Linux), contained within the APK (which is to say zip file) container.

During install, a library suitable for the device's architecture (assuming a matching one is available in the APK) is automatically copied out of the apk container into the app's private directory, where it can be used at runtime by the dynamic linker.